# не могу разобраться как выводит число в обратном порядке

Tags: python

Напишите программу, в которой задается целое число n [1:9] и выводится пирамида из n ступенек,
i-я ступень должна состоять из чисел от 1 до i и обратно без пробелов.

Пример вывода:

```
#     1
#    121
#   21231
#  1234321
# 123454321
```

Я пытался делать:

```
# for i in range(1, 10):
#     for j in range(1, i):
#         print(j, end='')
#     print()
```

Comment: а что конкретно не получается? Тут не решают задачи за других с нуля. И что с третьей строкой в примере, разве так и должно быть?

Comment: непонимаю, как обратно число выводить, благодарю Вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    for j in range((n - i - 1)):
        print(' ', end="")
    for j in range(i + 1):
        print(j + 1, end='')
    for j in range(i):
        print(i + 1 - (j + 1), end='')
    
    print()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
N = 5
print(*[(''.join(map(str,range(1,i+2)))+''.join(map(str,range(i,0,-1)))).center(N*2-1) for i in range(N)],sep='\n')
```

Или так

```
print(*[('12345678'[:i]+'987654321'[-i-1:]).center(N*2-1) for i in range(N)],sep='\n')
```